# How to set checkbox if validation fails?

Tags: 7, forms

I am creating a form which has checkbox, and options for checkbox are coming dynamically. In submit function I am rebuilding form if validation fails. all values are rendering but previously checked checkbox is not checking.

below is the code:

```
function modulename_form(){
      $header = array();
      $rows = array();
      $conditions = '';
      $orderby = array( 'pass_lname' => 'ASC'); 
      $unmapped_data = capcup_get_unmapped_passengers_data($conditions , $orderby);

      foreach ($unmapped_data as $key => $value) {
        $user = user_load($value->pass_uid);
        $insertion = !empty($value->pass_insertion)? $value->pass_insertion . ' ': '';
        if (empty($buttons)) {
          $row['name'] = '<a href="mailto:'  . $user->mail . '">' . check_plain($value->pass_lname . ' ' . $insertion . $value->pass_fname) . '</a>';
        }
        else {
          $row['name'] = '<a target="_blank" href="/passagier/'  . $value->passenger_uid . '">' . check_plain($value->passenger_lname . ' ' . $insertion . $value->passenger_fname) . '</a>';
        }
        $row['phone'] = $value->pass_tel;
        $row['practicecode'] = $value->pass_practcode;    
          $form['active'] =  array(
          '#type' => 'checkbox',
          '#return_value' => $value->pass_uid,
          '#attributes' => array(
              'name' => array('nodes[' . $value->pass_uid . ']'),
            )
          );
          $row['active'] =  drupal_render($form['active']);
        $rows[$value->pass_uid] = $row;
      }

      $form['nodes'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'table',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#rows' => $rows,
        '#empty' => t('No passenger available.'),
      );
return $form;
}
```

submit function:

```
function modulename_submit($form, $form_state) {
  if (in_array('boat', $account->roles)) {
      $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
      form_set_error('boat_user_info][emailaddress', 'Dit e-mailadres is al in gebruik.');
      return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I am writing form function like above because to get structure like below image:
[image]

When form will rebuilt all fields will remembered there previous value but checkbox is not remembered its value. I tried by adding `default_value` and all but not worked. Please suggest me how can I achieve that.

Comment: Can you show me where and how you add #default_value for this checkbox in the form function?

Answer (score 0):

All form validations should be done in form validate function and not in submit function. Read this [article](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/howtos/how-to-make-a-simple-module-with-a-form-and-menu-link)

Hope it helps. :)